# Woocommerce Zone Based minimum Amount

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

How Can ı set this situation ?

How can i add minimum order limit to flat rate product by zone ?

we can only free shipping products.

Comment: [This plugin](https://www.pluginhive.com/product/woocommerce-table-rate-shipping-pro-plugin/) have settings option to do this.

Comment: When asking a question in StackOverFlow, we expect you to add in your question your code attempt with enough details and explanations. Please, note that stackOverFlow is not a free coding service and also *"seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, plugins…"* is off topic. Please have a look. to [*"how to ask"*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: thank you, i am trying develop my english, and translate app's doesnt translate truely, sorry. but i searched other topics. sorry again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following for this, based on the zone id

```php
function zone_based_minimum_amount() {
    // Only run it in Cart or Checkout pages
    if( is_cart() || ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) ) {
        // HERE below your targeted zone IDs
        $targeted_zones_ids = array( 1, 2 );

        $chosen_methods = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' ); // The chosen shipping mehod
        $chosen_method = explode(':', reset($chosen_methods) );
        $shipping_zone = WC_Shipping_Zones::get_zone_by( 'instance_id', $chosen_method[1] );
        $zone_name = $shipping_zone->get_zone_name(); // Get the zone name
        $zone_id = $shipping_zone->get_id(); // Get the zone ID

        // Total (before taxes and shipping charges)
        $total = WC()->cart->subtotal;

         // HERE Set minimum cart total amount
        $min_total = 100;

        // Add an error notice is cart total is less than the minimum required      
        if( $total <= $min_total && in_array( $zone_id, $targeted_zones_ids ) ) {
            // Display an error message
            wc_add_notice( '<strong>' . sprintf(
                __("A minimum total purchase amount of %s is required to checkout."),
                wc_price($min_total)
            ) . '<strong>', 'error' );

            // Removing the Proceed to checkout button from the Cart page
            remove_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout', 'woocommerce_button_proceed_to_checkout', 20 );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'zone_based_minimum_amount', 10, 0 );
```

Comment: where should i add this code, and thank you sooo much, 
function.php ? i tried function.php but, didn't run.and i added ALL zone's id 
https://prnt.sc/sace4u